# How to increase tableview cell's contenview's size? (not using customtableviewcell)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I tried with cell.contentview.bounds but it gives error that it is not assignable something. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

use `tableView delegate` method :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     return 80; //returns height for the tableview cell    

  }
```

Comment: it just increase the height of uitableview cell and its subviews but not its contentviews..

Answer (score 1):

you just need 1 line of code ....

```
[tableview setRowHeight:100];
```

Comment: it just increase the height of uitableview cell and its subviews but not its contentviews..